# Как из яндекс карты забрать координаты?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, вот у меня на сайте есть яндекс карта, я ввожу в неё определённый адресс, он отображается. Как сделать, чтобы координаты отображались в отдельных блоках coord1, coord2?

вот сайт:
http://u0763918test1.isp.regruhosting.ru/

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; border: 5px solid red"></div>
<p>Широта</p>
<div class="coord1"></div>
<p>Долгота</p>
<div class="coord2"></div>

ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 7,
    controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl', 'typeSelector',  'fullscreenControl', 'routeButtonControl']
}, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Так устроит?

```js
var lat = 55.76;
var lng = 37.64;

var coord1 = document.querySelector('.coord1');
var coord2 = document.querySelector('.coord2');

coord1.innerHTML = lat;
coord2.innerHTML = lng;

ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [lat, lng],
        zoom: 7,
        controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl', 'typeSelector',  'fullscreenControl', 'routeButtonControl']
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; border: 5px solid red"></div>
<p>Широта</p>
<div class="coord1"></div>
<p>Долгота</p>
<div class="coord2"></div>
```

Comment: не работает, как были изначальные координаты, так и остались

Comment: @Pavel вы спрашивали как вывести )) Чтобы это при смене работало, вам нужно с API яндекс карт разбираться. С разделом поиска если быть точнее. 
Вот тут есть типовое решение https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/geocode-docpage/